# Android XML, how to make app compatible only for phones and tablets?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-manifest, screen

I need to make my application compatible only for phones and tablets (all phones and tablets specifically) and I know i have to declare this in the manifest file but does not work.

Here my tries:

```
<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

```
<compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
        <!-- all large size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

With this edits on the manifest the app is compatible only with phone and tablets but not for all of them. How can I do to make app compatible for all of them? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me in order to make the app compatible only with phones and tablets (and run it in portrait mode) was adding this lines in my Manifest.xml file:

```
    <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>
    <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />
    <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Comment: does this work out only for all the mobiles and tablets?

Comment: @Rameshbabu yeah, those properties removed useless devices (for my usecase) like chromebooks or android TVs

Comment: great to hear about this. One more thing we wanted to do is to restrict devices like this as well:->   Unknown | Wearable | Android Automotive

Comment: @Rameshbabu those properties removes also wearables, since they dont have a camera and the flash. And if you wanna remove ALL the automotive devices its pretty simple: in the google play console remove that category and it will be incompatible for all your future releases. If this was helpful, consider to upvote my original answer. Thanks

Comment: Sure will upvote once after applying these changes in live. Thank you so much for your information. Will come back

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of that.  Those fields are for when you want to eliminate certain screen sizes/types.  For example, if you only wanted to work on small screens.  If you want to work on everything, you just don't put any of this at all-  everything is the default.

Now on the play store you may still then see some devices you won't work on.  This will largely be due to sdk version you support, and that's expected.  Or any require-feature flags in your manifest (which should only exist if you absolutely need that feature to work).

Comment: Yes but how can I do to support only phones and tablets? I dont want to remove manually from the console TV wearable and chromebook

Comment: Why would you want to?  If someone on those devices wants to use your app, why not let them?  If it physically will not work, then why won't it work-  use that as your excluding factor, trying to list everything to include and whitelist them in is always going to be harder than blacklisting on what really matters.

Comment: But screen size like that will never work.  A chromebook can be any of those sizes and densities.  And a TV, while it tends to have lower density, can also have different sizes and densities.  So your approach is just wrong to begin with.